# Is it possible to use bluetooth module hc-06 in Master mode

Tags: bluetooth

[These are](http://www.ebay.in/itm/Wireless-Bluetooth-RF-Transceiver-Module-RS232-TTL-HC-06-4-female-connectors-/161609209809?_trksid=p2054897.l4275) two popular modules available in market- HC05 and HC06

I bought two HC-06 modules and trying to establish communication between them.

But I failed and a friend of mine said it can be only be used as slave.   I verified this by establishing a successful communication between a laptop with Bluetooth, and this module with a Controller board.

But I am not able to understand why this module  is made in such a way.  Is it not possible to change the mode to master using some software upgrade ? If yes how ?

Answer (score 1):

The HC-05 and HC-06 are identical, except the firmware they get shipped with. For whatever reason, the HC-06 has a simpler, slave only firmware. The HC-05 has a much more completed command set. There was some attempts to reflash or change the firmwares on these but [the projects were a bit obscure.](http://hackaday.com/2012/01/30/firmware-programmer-for-a-cheap-bluetooth-module/) It's just cheaper and faster to get the HC-05 or a newer master capable bluetooth module.

Answer (score 0):

I do have those too but you need to send AT-commands to the module to switch it to master mode and establish connection. You need to refer to the manufacturer's manual for this.

Comment: You mean using AT commands one of it can be switched to master mode? can you send the link that describes this procedure?

Comment: @user25108 [This](http://www.instructables.com/id/AT-command-mode-of-HC-05-Bluetooth-module/?ALLSTEPS) may help.

Comment: According to that link "HC05 can act as both master and slave whereas HC06 functions only as slave".